# Trouble with finding class element names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to grab the Names of some Class Elements in a document (there are several of them) and rotate through them.

The HTML code of the site looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="item">
      <a class="item-name" href="http://somerandomurl.com">Relevant Item</a>
```

If I wanted to grab the URL I know the solution already:

```
function searchItem(itemname) {
    listings = $(".item-name");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        element = listing[i];
        if(element.href.indexOf(itemname) !== -1) {
            return true; 
          } 
    }
}
```

In this case however, I don't want to compare the URL against another URL, I need to grab the Title off the "item-name" class as String and compare it to other Strings.

How can I manage to do this? I have tried a few things already, like `listings = $(".market-name market-link").text();`.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: It's a real website and the javascript part would be a userscript. Does jsfiddle make sense in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function searchItem(itemname) {

    if($('a.item-name:contains("' + itemname + '")').length) {
        //console.log("true"); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyu151dm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

First, yo are looping through the wrong variable.

You should loop through **listing** instead of links

Then compare it to the element HTML:

```
function searchItem(itemname) {
    listings = $(".item-name");
    for(var i = 0; i < listing.length; i++) {
        element = listing[i];
        if(element.html().indexOf(itemname) !== -1) {
            return true; 
          } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a leftover cause I changed the original code to make it more explaining.

The problem is that `listings = $(".item-name");` doesn't return anything reasonable, if I print it via console.log it says: `Listing: [object Object]` instead of "Relevant Item". That's my problem and the reason I'm searching for help